# Pine-script Duplicate Signal Issue

Tags: pine-script

In order to ignore duplicate signals in the PineScript 2.0 environment, I followed the link above but nothing is visible.Can you see why it doesn't work?

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50013983/pinescript-duplicate-alerts)

Comment: Please provide more information, such as error messages and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid consecutive signals you will need to manage a boolean state using a technique like [this one](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-allow-transitions-from-condition-ab-or-ba-but-not-aa-nor-bb).

*Disclosure: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry. I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to the pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.*